# How can I use a variable of data parameters in an jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some difficulties to understand how to build a set of data values that I can use in an Ajax call (using jQuery). I have a function that generates some data values that I want to use in the Ajax call. In the code below I have simplified the `get_data` function to just return a string of data entries:

```
// get_data() will return a string:
// --> stringA: 'This is A', stringB: 'This is B', stringC: 'This is C'
function get_data() {
    var data = "";
    data += "stringA: 'This is A',";
    data += "stringB: 'This is B',";
    data += "stringC: 'This is C'";
    return data;
}

var my_variables = get_data();

$.ajax({
        url: "my_ajax_handler.php",
        data: {
            firstString: "Hello World!", 
            my_variables  // I would like this to expand to: stringA: 'This is A', stringB: 'This...etc'
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result){ 
            document.write(result);
        }
    });
```

This will obviously not work, since the `my_variables` is a clean string and won't be treated as three separate data values. In the `my_ajax_handler` I have the following code:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This will result in the following output:

```
Array
(
    [firstString] => Hello World!
    [my_variables] => stringA: 'This is A',stringB: 'This is B',stringC: 'This is C'
)
```

I.e. the data values are treated as one single string. What do I need to do to get the following output?

```
Array
(
    [firstString] => Hello World!
    [stringA] => This is A
    [stringB] => This is B
    [stringC] => This is C
)
```

Comment: Make `data` like this : `data: {"firstString" : "Hello World!",  "stringA" : "This is A", "stringB" : "This is B","stringC" : "This is C"},`. No need of `get_data()` in that case

Comment: If you have control over the `getData()` function, change it to return an object instead of a string.

Comment: Also, if this is a pure JS problem, please don't tag it with PHP. Otherwise, please share more details about how PHP is involved

Comment: @NicoHaase, You're right... I removed the PHP tag. It wasn't necessary to use that tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this:

```
function get_data(data) {
    data['stringA'] = "This is A";
    data['stringB'] = "This is B";
    data['stringC'] = "This is C";
    return data;
}

var myPostData = {};

myPostData['firstString'] = "Hello World!";
myPostData = get_data(myPostData);

$.ajax({
    url: "my_ajax_handler.php",
    data: myPostData,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        document.write(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to send the data this way, any value within a cell in an array

```
function get_data() {
   var data = [];
    data['stringA'] = 'This is A';
    data['stringB'] = 'This is B';
    data['stringC'] = 'This is C';
    return data;
}
```